# SharePoint 2013: How to filter search documents based on stamp property on document library

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

1. Currently, all documents are shown in search result
2. I have stamped property on document library level across site collection
   Example: Document library having stamp property ‘MyDocumentLibrary: true”
3. My requirement is to show documents from only those document library whose stamp property is present on document library 
   i.e. I wanted to filter out documents from other document library

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible in SharePoint Online. 
First you need to find Crawled Property containing word "...MyDocumentLibrary..."
Then based on this property you need to create Managed Property. Provide name (e.g. "MyDocumentLibrary") and check Queryable option.

Do a Full Crawl.

You need to open search result page to edit. Then edit search result webpart.
Click "Change Query" and add: MyDocumentLibrary=true. 
Save & publish.